# how to check the specific files is present in folder or not in automated way in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have 1000 of the folders in each of their different pdf files available. I have go into each folder and check whether their specific file( for example folder is named as school0001 and files is named as following it schoool_1m.pdf, schoool_2m.pdf.. schoool_10m.pdf) now I have go into the first folder and check all the month 1 to month 10 pdf available or not like that I have to check all the 1000 folder (the folder are named into school0001 ...........school1000.) after the check it. I have created a data frame as follows.

### I want the result as follows

if the _m1.pdf is present in the folder it has yes or no in data frame like that for all the 10 files in each folder (totally 1000 folder)

```
s1          m1        m2   ...     m10

school0001  yes      yes          yes
school0002  no       yes          yes
school0003  yes      no          yes
..
..
..
school1000  yes      yes          yes
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to create a [mcve](/help/mcve) first

```py
import os
import random
import pandas as pd
# this create an empty file
def touch(path):
    with open(path, 'a'):
        os.utime(path, None)

fldr = "main_folder"
for i in range(10):
    new_fldr = os.path.join(fldr, f"school{i:03d}")
    os.makedirs(new_fldr, exist_ok=True)
    for k in range(5):
        fn = random.randint(1,10)
        fn = os.path.join(new_fldr, f"m{fn}.pdf")
        touch(fn)
```

Now we have 10 folders with (up to) 5 files each with random names. Then we want to read all files nested inside `main folder`

```py
def recursive_get_files(path):
    out = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        if len(filenames) > 0:
            out += [os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
                     for fn in filenames]
    return out

out = recursive_get_files(fldr)

# we put these filenames on a df
df = pd.DataFrame({"fn":out})

# split rname and remove the first one
df["fn"] = df["fn"].str.split("/").str[1:]

# expand list to columns
df = pd.DataFrame(df['fn'].values.tolist(), columns=['fldr','fn'])

# These are existing files
df["exist"] = True

# Use pivot_table

pv = pd.pivot_table(df,
                    index="fldr",
                    columns="fn",
                    values="exist")\
       .fillna(False)
```

**EDIT** given that the expand list to columns doesn't work you could try these alternatives

### Alternative 1

```py
df = df["fn"].apply(pd.Series)
df.columns = ['fldr','fn']
```

### Alternative 2

```py
df["fldr"] = df["fn"].str[0]
df["fn"] = df["fn"].str[1]
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0ef9989af919> in <module>
     16 
     17 # expand list to columns
---> 18 df = pd.DataFrame(df['fn'].values.tolist(), columns=['fldr','fn'])
    
AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns

Comment: in this line # expand list to columns
df = pd.DataFrame(df['fn'].values.tolist(), columns=['fldr','fn'])

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: files name should be same as folder name example school0001 is folder name and file name school0001_m1.pdf,  school0001_m2.pdf,  .. school0001_m10.pdf,

Comment: python 3  is version i am using @rpanai

Comment: I'm asking for `pd.__version__`

Comment: its pandas: 0.24.2

Comment: weird I'm on 0.24.1. Ill try to look for an alternative

Comment: Added two alternative ways to expand lists to columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# the path to your folder
folder_path = r'some\path\to\your\folder'
# list the directories in the folder path
folders = os.listdir(folder_path)

# create an empty list to append to
dfs = []

# iterate through all the folders in your path
for folder in folders:
    # f-string to create the path to each individual folder
    path = f'{folder_path}\\{folder}'
    # list comprehension to get the file names: school_m1, school_m2
    files = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename)).split('.')[0] for filename in glob.glob(f'{path}\\*.pdf')]
    # create a list of all your _m values
    m = [f.split('_')[1] for f in files]
    # create a dataframe where the index is the folder name and the columns are the _m values
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=[folder], columns=m).fillna('Yes')
    # append dataframe to the empty list
    dfs.append(df)

# create a final dataframe by concatenating all the dataframes in the list
final_df = pd.concat(dfs).fillna('No')

            m1  m10   m4   m6   m2   m8
school001  Yes  Yes  Yes  Yes   No   No
school002  Yes   No   No  Yes  Yes  Yes
```

## folders in my test path

[image]

## files in folders

[image]

Comment: 7     # create a list of all your _m values
----> 8     m = [f.split('_')[1] for f in files]
      9     # create a dataframe where the index is the folder name and the columns are the _m values
     10     df = pd.DataFrame(index=[folder], columns=m).fillna('Yes')

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `m = [f.split('')[1] for f in files]` you are not splitting `f` on anything so index of `1` is our of range. In my example I split on `'_'` because your question stated that the file names are `school_m1` that code would split that string to `['school', 'm1']` so you call the second element because we only want the `m1`. when you split on an empty string you would get `['school_m1']` which is the zero element in the list